# load firebase data in angular 4 table

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am working on angular 4 project for database I am using firebse. I am using smart-table of angular in it for delete function of table data it requires firebase key for every record so I get it from firebase but I can't load that data in my table following is my code

I have write function in service as follow

```
getEData(): Observable<any[]>  
 {
    return this.af.list('/enquirydata').snapshotChanges();
 }
```

the component.ts of table's page as follow

```
 source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();


  items: Array<any> = [];


  constructor(private service: SmartTableService, private router: Router) {
 this.service.getEData().subscribe(k=> {  
  k.map(c=> {
  console.log(c.payload.val());

  this.items.push(c);
  })
  console.log(this.items);
  });


    this.source.load(this.items);
    console.log(this.source);

    }
```

here `c.payload.val()` contains the actual data while `c` have data with metadata like key and other data.

now I am unable to load this data in my table how should I do that any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
getEData(): Observable<any[]>  
 {
    return this.af.list('/enquirydata').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
 }
```

Comment: how should I call it in component.ts

Comment: Same way you calling right now, tyis time c.payload.val() won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Observable and Subscribe operate asynchronously.

There may be nothing in **this.items** when **this.source.load(this.items)** is called.

Try change to synchronous mode(Non Observable)

Or detect when **this.items.push(c)** is called, and call **this.source.load(this.items)**

Or put **this.source.load(this.items)** after **this.items.push(c)**. As shown below.

```
constructor(private service: SmartTableService, private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getEData().subscribe(k => {  
    k.map(c => {
      this.items.push(c);
      this.source.load(this.items);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: can you give solution for it

Comment: can u help me for delete function as well plz